# Java non static field

Tags: java

```
public class UDP implements Runnable {

    private String host;
    private int port;
    private int delay;
    private int timeout;

    @Override
    public void handlePacket(String host, int port, int delay, int timeout) {
        UDP.host = host;
        UDP.port = port;
        UDP.delay = delay;
        UDP.timeout = timeout;
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(new UDP());
    }
```

The error im getting is non static field cannot be referenced to static context 
I have no idea what i should do, i know a little java but i am totally lost

Comment: You just permanently leaked a thread.

Comment: This question concerns a basic, fundamental aspect of object-oriented programming in general (not just Java).  In my view, you ought to have looked to the online Java tutorial or any of the excellent Java sites for the answer to this question.  Your first instinct should not have been to post this question to SO.

Comment: You should be using `this`, not `new UDP()`, as the argument to `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute()`.

Answer (score 6):

Using the class name as a prefix indicates that you are attempting to use a static context.

To assign a value to an instance variable, don't prefix it with the class name, prefix it with `this`:

```
this.host = host;
...
```

Additionally, using `this` is only necessary because you named your parameters the same as your instance variables.